# How to add quiz (closed questions) to a Julia Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, jupyter

In a Julia notebook I would like to add an interactive quiz, with closed questions and possibly feedbacks (similar to the Moodle quiz activity).
Is there any option for it?

Comment: Pluto.jl might be an alternative, there are easy to use integrations of [interactive HTML elements](https://github.com/fonsp/PlutoUI.jl).

Comment: Yeah, I think they did that for the MIT class using Pluto

Comment: I ended up using Literate.jl, Documenter.jl and QuizQuestions.jl